# Asymmetrical meniscus in certain glassware

Tags: fluid-dynamics, water, material-science, physical-chemistry, surface-tension

I work in a lab that does tests on water samples, and one test we do measures COD or Chemical Oxygen Demand. For quality control, we have a COD standard which contains a certain amount of Potassium Hydrogen Phthalate that consumes oxygen at a known rate to standardize our measurements. My supervisor and I have noticed that, in certain volumetric flasks (but not in other, seemingly identical flasks from the same manufacturer), the meniscus is not concave or convex, but rather seems to prefer to stick to one side of the flask's neck. In other words, the liquid is highest on one side of the glass and lowest on the other.
[image: Not the best picture, it's more pronounced when the flask is more full]

I've never seen this phenomenon anywhere else and can't even find an image of it online. The only thing I can think of is that the Phthalate has a substantially different surface tension compared to water, and that combined with certain wear patterns on glass will make the two liquids separate somewhat at the top. Any ideas?

Comment: I see bubbles and droplets on the left side. Does the asymmetry consistently point in the direction that the liquid was just poured from? Also, does this phenomenon persist with different liquids, e.g. distilled water? My guess would be that as the flask is tilted back upright, at some point just before it becomes totally upright the surface tension of the asymmetric water-air boundary becomes strong enough withstand the asymmetric weight/pressure of the water. I suspect a way to consistently produce this is by very slowly tilting the flask upright.

Comment: @ArturodonJuan The flasks are vigorously shaken after being prepared, which produces the air bubbles, but this effect only appears in some of them (5 flasks were prepared today, and 4 of them showed the asymmetry). Liquid is added to the flask via pipettors and squeeze bottles, the former of which doesn't interact with the neck walls, and the latter of which spirals down the neck, not seeming to favor any particular side. It seems additional testing is needed to clear out some variables.

Answer (score 2):

That suggests a patchy adsorbed layer of something foreign on the glass surface itself. I recommend you do a chromic acid dip & rinse, dry, & retest.